# laravel 4.2 のエラー行数は表示可能？

Tags: php, laravel

laravel 4.2を使用しております。
viewなどでエラーが出た際には

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

などのエラーメッセージは表示されるのですが、エラーの行数が表示されません。
表示することは可能でしょうか？
バッチも同様にエラー行数が表示されません。こちらも表示することは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

バッチまでは調べていませんが、View のエラーは表示されます。

`php artisan env` が `local` であれば "Whoops!" というエラー画面が表示されるはずです。
[image: エラー画面]

この四角で囲んだところが行になります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、参考にさせていただきます。
バッチのやコントローラーのところでもエラーが出たときに原因特定まで時間がかかってしまうのでcomposer でインストールできるものが用意されていたらやりたいなぁとおもっておりました